# ng-href not responding other than updating link or addressbar when i clieck on it (Angular Js)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've ng-href which replace values in href that will be ok but when i click on the link, It change url on address bar which is working correct to but doesn't process to execute that URL.

What's blocking url to process? I've taken off ng-click method off from the link as well.

```
<li id="tst_productList_categoryLeftNav_categoryFacet_{{categoryFacet.categoryId}}" ng-repeat="categoryFacet in vm.products.categoryFacets | orderBy : 'shortDescription'"
ng-class="{'f-selected' : categoryFacet.selected}">

<a href="javascript:;" ng-href="/search?categoryId={{categoryFacet.categoryId}}&filters={{vm.filters}}&sortby={{vm.sortBy}}&page={{vm.page}}&pageSize={{vm.pageSize}}&criteria={{vm.criteria}}&view={{vm.view}}&columns={{vm.columns}}">
<span class="f-name">{{categoryFacet.shortDescription}}</span>
<span class="f-count">({{categoryFacet.count}})</span>
</a>
</li>
```

what's blocking link?

Comment: Why have you included href="javascript:;"?

Comment: Yeah, because there was ng-click, but even i take that href="javascript:;" off, still it's not going to that URL. Page stays there.

Comment: do you get any error on console when you click on `ng-href` ? Also, try to hardcode the string as `href` and check whether its something related to your code. If it doesn't redirect using `href` as well then it has nothing to do with `ng-href`

Answer (score 1):

`ng-href` directive internally creates `href` attribute. Try removing the `href` attribute that you have added manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `target="_self"`
to `<a>` element

```html
<a target="_self" ng-href="/search?categoryId={{categoryFacet.categoryId}}&filters={{vm.filters}}&sortby={{vm.sortBy}}&page={{vm.page}}&pageSize={{vm.pageSize}}&criteria={{vm.criteria}}&view={{vm.view}}&columns={{vm.columns}}">
```